# Git server - prevent all incoming pushes from any computer except one

Tags: git, hook, server-side, githooks

I want the git server to reject any incoming pushes that aren't from one particular machine on the local network for a specific branch (or branches).

I'm wondering if there is a solution to this or not as I've been looking around a bit about git hooks, however as far as I can tell there is very little information sent with the "git push" command to the server.

I have a solution by putting the pre-commit and pre-push hooks onto every machine that will be pushing to the repo, however I'm wanting to find a server-side solution instead, if it exists.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your clients use SSH protocol for pushes, you can compare `$SSH_CLIENT` in your `update` hook script on server.

The branch name can be extracted from the first argument passed to the update hook.